# jQuery do something when an own function is ready

Tags: jquery, events, function, parallel-processing, ready

I'd like to priorize my functions.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
drawMap();
on showLinks() ready do drawChart();
});
```

How can i do this with jQuery?

Thanks, Répás

Comment: If `showLinks` is defined in a SCRIPT block that is above the current one, then it's ready.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Gary already mentioned in his answer, you'd only want to do this if you are dealing with asynchronous execution.

You might want to take a look on [deferreds](http://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/) that was introduced in jQuery 1.5.

In your case it would look something like this:

```
$(function(){
    drawMap();
    $.when(showLinks())
        .then(drawChart);
});
```

To make the above work you must make sure that the `showLinks` function return a [promise](http://api.jquery.com/deferred.promise/) and that it triggers [`resolve`](http://api.jquery.com/deferred.resolve/) once it's done executing.

```
function showLinks(){
    var dfd = $.Deferred();

    // Add your asynchronous code here
    setTimeout(function(){
        console.log("Links shown!");
        dfd.resolve(); 
    }, 1000);

    return dfd.promise();
}
```

Check [test case on jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mekwall/g4dBN/1/)

Comment: @Gary, indeed! I've just put together a test case on jsFiddle. Added a link to it in my answer!

Answer (score 1):

call showLinks() inside drawMap()
call drawChart() inside and at the end showLinks()

Comment: It's not good for me, i'd like to keep the structure for the afterworks.

Comment: check below, it's interesting

Answer (score 1):

- If `showLinks() & drawMaps()` isn't asynchronous then just call `drawChart()` straight after:

  ```
  $(document).ready(function(){
     drawMap();
     showLinks();
     drawChart();
  });
  ```
- Otherwise supply a callback to `showLinks()`:

  ```
  function showLinks(callback)
  {
      /* your code */
      callback();
  }

  $(document).ready(function(){
     drawMap();
     showLinks(drawChart);
  });
  ```

It's hard to tell what is and isn't synchronous and asynchronous in your code, but in any case supplying callbacks, as in the example above, is the way forward.

Answer (score 0):

Can you throw a custom event from your showLinks() function ? Then you can catch this event and react accordingly

It's a fine play between `bind` and `trigger`. Here are the [docs](http://api.jquery.com/category/events/)